# Notifications and AlarmManager - cancelling the alarm I set

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, alarmmanager

I am making a sample app just for educational purposes, where I create a notification every minute. I also have a button to cancel the alarm.

What I do is that when the notification comes, I click it and click the unset button I have set to run unsetAlarm(). But it continues to bother me every minute.

How do I stop the notifications? Could it be that the activity is somehow duplicated? If this is the case, how do I ensure there is only one instance of the MainActivity?

**MainActivity class**

```
package no.perandersen.notifyontimeexample;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private PendingIntent notifyIntent;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    }


    public void setAlarm(View v) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                NotificationService.class);

        notifyIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0,
                myIntent, 0);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
        Log.v(TAG, "time for alarm trigger:" + calendar.getTime().toString());
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1 * 60 * 1000, notifyIntent);
    }

    public void unsetAlarm(View v) {
        alarmManager.cancel(notifyIntent);
        Log.v(TAG, "cancelling notification");
    }

}
```

**NotificationService class**

```
package no.perandersen.notifyontimeexample;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

public class NotificationService extends Service {

    private NotificationManager nm;
    private static final String TAG = "NotificationService";
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        Log.v(TAG, "on onCreate");

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Log.v(TAG, "on onStartCommand");
        Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, mainActivityIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("bothering you")
                .setContentText("Just bothering you from example code")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notification.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        nm.notify(0, notification); 

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are calling setAlarm and unsetAlarm from?

Comment: onClick attribute of the activity_main.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that to cancel an `Alarm` you need to recreate the `PendingIntent` exactly how you created it when you set the alarm. So change your `unsetAlarm()` to

```
  public void unsetAlarm(View v) {
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
            NotificationService.class);
    notifyIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0,
            myIntent, 0);  // recreate it here before calling cancel

    alarmManager.cancel(notifyIntent);
    Log.v(TAG, "cancelling notification");
}
```

Comment: I am looking into android:launchMode="singleInstance" now for the manifest, might be better. I will check this afterwards

Comment: anyways, in my code, I cancel using the exact same PendingIntent. I have stored it in a field. That should not be a problem should it?

Comment: Ok. this works. But why can I not store it in a field and reuse it?

Comment: To be honest I'm not quite sure why. I could make guesses but I've never looked into it much. I just always cancel it this way so there's no problems. Maybe if you leave the `Activity` or a new instance of this `Activity` is created then that old reference is scrapped. Glad I could help but sorry I couldn't give a better explanation

Comment: You could try `singleInstance` instead of `singleTask`. `singleTask` still creates a new instance of the `Activity` but only allows one instance of the `Activity` and only one task on the stack. I would still recommend doing it the way that I suggested in case GC scraps the reference to the `PendingIntent` or some other unforeseen circumstance

Comment: I use singeInstance. Does not work. But thank you, solving the problem was the goal :)