# Reuse in Android - why can I not set a repeating alarm and cancel it using the same instance of a PendingIntent?

Tags: android, field, reusability, android-pendingintent

When binding onClick in activity_main.xml to setAlarm to one button and unsetAlarm to another button in the same activity, the following code will not let you unset the alarm when clicking the button linked to the unsetAlarm method.

```
...package name and includes ommitted...

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private PendingIntent notifyIntent;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    }


    public void setAlarm(View v) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                NotificationService.class);

        notifyIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0,
                myIntent, 0);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
        Log.v(TAG, "time for alarm trigger:" + calendar.getTime().toString());
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1 * 60 * 1000, notifyIntent);
    }

    public void unsetAlarm(View v) {
        alarmManager.cancel(notifyIntent);
        Log.v(TAG, "cancelling notification");
    }

}
```

The solution was to (as I was provided in [Notifications and AlarmManager - cancelling the alarm I set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306600/notifications-and-alarmmanager-cancelling-the-alarm-i-set)) recreate the pendingIntent in the unsetAlarm method:

```
  public void unsetAlarm(View v) {
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
            NotificationService.class);
    notifyIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0,
            myIntent, 0);  // recreate it here before calling cancel

    alarmManager.cancel(notifyIntent);
    Log.v(TAG, "cancelling notification");
}
```

My question is: Why can I not reuse the PendingIntent, stored in the field "notifyIntent" in the first code snippet? Why do I have to recreate it to cancel it? I have set the  of MainActivity to have the attribute **android:launchMode="singleInstance"** so I should believe it was using the same instance when I click the notification created in the NotificationService (I have ommitted it but it just shows a notification).